# Why didn't bomb blast near portal terminus destroy space-time fracture?

Tags: tv, terra-nova

After making portal go both ways, when Lucas was near portal terminus & Taylor threatened him to shoot, he showed with fingers that portal was open & said that Sonics would destroy space-time fracture. Taylor listened & didn't shoot. Means, he knew this fact.

Plus, Hope Plaza destruction in 2149 destroyed space-time fracture because Hope Plaza was linked with space-time fracture at that time.

But, when a human bomb came from portal terminus (who said: Help Me) and blasted, nothing happened to space-time fracture. Why? Portal was open at that time and that degree of blast (which was more destructive that pulse sonic) could definitely destroy space-time fracture..

Comment: I don't think the fracture was destroyed in 2149, the equipment that used the fracture to create the portal is what was destroyed.

Comment: Having trouble remembering the direct specifics for a more fully qualified answer overall, but regarding the the blast itself, I don't believe it was open in a bi-directional capacity at the time. I think this was a *normal* pilgrimage only requiring uni-directional travel. I don't think we had any indicator that the portal was open both ways when the human timebomb came through.

Comment: @Izakta Watch last episode again. After Lucas became free, he tried contacting troops near portal and told them: "Hope Plaza is under attack. Tell them to power it down or unlink it from fracture. Or, we'll lose it." (Not Exact Words)

Comment: @Josh See my previous comment... it was independent of uni or bi status.

Comment: I think in that last episode, the portal was open bi-directionally since they were sending stuff back to their timeline and there was an expectation of being able to return to Terra Nova, however, it *could* be that there's no dependency on having timelines linked through a bi-directional portal at all. It COULD be that the fracture would be vulnerable from any side that was 'transmitting' to other timeline. Before Lucas, this was never something that would have been an issue from the Terra Nova side. Human bomb may not have fractured it since TN was only receiving.

Comment: @Josh Fine... worth an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not withstanding the debate about whether a fracture could truly occur, the question here is centered around why the human bomb sent in advance of the raiding party did not cause such a fracture to occur according to the rules expressed in-Universe [which characters seem to believe, even if wrongly].

The ability to collapse the space-time fracture, requires the trigger (explosion, sonic device, etc) to occur, at the very least, on the side of portal that's transmitting. Whether there's a requirement that the portal must be operating in a bi-directional capacity (i.e, matter able to traverse both directions at the same time) is unknown. However, we can presume that the danger presented in the scene between Lucas and Taylor was a new development for Terra Nova because the portal was reversed and the terminus was transmitting rather than receiving. It could be that this general knowledge/fear/theory was always a point of concern and viable danger in their original timeline (Hope Plaza side).

Why didn't the fracture collapse when the human bomb came through and went boom?

At that point in time, Terra Nova was receiving a standard pilgrimage. There's no reason to believe that the terminus in TN was *also* transmitting. The terminus was operating on TN side in the same capacity it had prior to Lucas' discovery, therefore no blow back through the fracture. It was 'innert' so to speak and destroying it would only have unanchored it from the fracture.

Comment: You shouldn't say, characters seem to believe it wrongly. Today's physics is in no position to even describe such fracture. You can't apply it to that.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - I agree with your comment, though in clarity, I said 'even if wrongly' to leave room between what they believe and could be real within their own universe. I was attempting to treat their current understanding as the currently accepted theories even though it could easily be that they are wrong as well. They've exploited the space-time fracture, but that doesn't mean they completely understand it either. I wasn't trying to impose any of our physics on them directly. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall that the space-time fracture was never in danger of being destroyed, only the machinery that anchored the fracture to that particular location. When the anchoring machinery is destroyed, the fracture moves to a random other location, and I think *that* was what Taylor was scared of.

Comment: Read first paragraph of my question and watch last episode again. After Lucas became free, he tried contacting troops near portal and told them: "Hope Plaza is under attack. Tell them to power it down or unlink it from fracture. Or, we'll lose it." (Not Exact Words)

Comment: The Fracture existed before it was discovered. (At least that is what we are currently lead to believe.) All this device did was to bind the fracture to a particular location rather than having it hopping across the landscape. Think of the device as you would a stargate, making a single exit point rather than a twisting thread that would move around the landscape randomly.

Comment: @Thaddeus Don't apply logics.. The fracture was destroyed in last. Watch last episode again.

Comment: @Thaddeus When portal was open, the blast was able to hit fracture.. that's the point. Offline device destruction could definitely not destroy fracture..

Comment: Anything capable of creating a stable wormhole through 65 million years should be able to withstand a puny chemical explosive. The energy required to hold a stable link between the two locations should be greater than any energy use by humanity since the beginning of civilization. Should the show be renewed (still in question) we will find the fracture is still around or others will be found.

Comment: @Thaddeus Its just your assumption.. How can you apply today's physics to that time tech?

Comment: @Thaddeus Its another thing: If season 2 is launched, they would bring back fracture in existence somehow... :)

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure they wouldn't. That would completely destroy all their work building up last season to its destruction. If Fox manages to shop it out to another network, they'll be making a move on the Bad Lands, and probably a bit more focus on dinosaur fights than last season.